# mysqli update prepare Uncaught exception

Tags: php, for-loop, mysqli

the // $update line works just fine, but the prepared statement throws this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message
>   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE weekday = ?' at line 5

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){ //update all time fields 
//  $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE storehours SET open='$open[$i]', open_2='$open_2[$i]', close='$close[$i]', close_2='$close_2[$i]' WHERE weekday ='$weekday[$i]'");

            mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE maxfoo SET open = ?,
                       open_2 = ?,
                       close = ?,
                       close_2 = ?,
                       WHERE weekday = ?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("sssss",
                       $open[$i],
                       $open_2[$i],
                       $close[$i],
                       $close_2[$i],
                       $weekday[$i]);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();

        }
```

the code seems perfect to me unless i'm not allowed to use a loop? i'm not sure what the syntax error is.

Comment: Don't prepare the statement inside the loop, otherwise you're negating the performance benefits of a prepared statement.... prepare it before the loop, and only bind the arguments inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the comma at the end of `close_2 = ?,` before starting `WHERE...`

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE maxfoo SET open = ?,
                   open_2 = ?,
                   close = ?,
                   close_2 = ?
                   WHERE weekday = ?");
```

Comment: what about the comma on the bind_param section?

Comment: That's different, you need that to separate the parameters you are passing to `bind_param()`.

Comment: not really, don't remove commas from bind stmt because you had a syntax error in your SQL statement, not in your PHP code

Comment: cool that fixed it, the odd thing is alot of my other update commands have that comma, and run just fine, why is that?

Comment: @AlbertD having a comma right before `WHERE...` will result in a query error, every time